# check whether value changed over time within group dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, tidyverse

I have a df looking like:

```
# A tibble: 14 x 3
   user_id flag  order
     <dbl> <chr> <dbl>
 1       1 aaa       1
 2       1 aaa       2
 3       1 aaa       3
 4       1 bbb       4
 5       2 bbb       1
 6       2 bbb       2
 7       3 aaa       1
 8       3 aaa       2
 9       3 bbb       3
10       4 ccc       1
11       4 aaa       2
12       4 aaa       3
13       4 aaa       4
14       4 aaa       5



test_df <- tibble::tribble(
             ~user_id, ~flag, ~order,
                    1, "aaa",      1,
                    1, "aaa",      2,
                    1, "aaa",      3,
                    1, "bbb",      4,
                    2, "bbb",      1,
                    2, "bbb",      2,
                    3, "aaa",      1,
                    3, "aaa",      2,
                    3, "bbb",      3,
                    4, "ccc",      1,
                    4, "aaa",      2,
                    4, "aaa",      3,
                    4, "aaa",      4,
                    4, "aaa",      5)
```

- user_id: unique identifier for each user
- flag (string)
- order

I want to check whether the flag for each user_id has changed over the order.

I want to create a column `has_changed` valued:

- `has_changed` if the flag has changed to `bbb` at some point after `order` value is != from 1.

I did:

```
test_df %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  mutate(has_changed = ifelse(any(flag == 'bbb' & order != 1), 'yes','no'))
```

Resulting in:

```
# A tibble: 14 x 4
# Groups:   user_id [4]
   user_id flag  order has_changed
     <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>      
 1       1 aaa       1 yes        
 2       1 aaa       2 yes        
 3       1 aaa       3 yes        
 4       1 bbb       4 yes        
 5       2 bbb       1 yes        
 6       2 bbb       2 yes        
 7       3 aaa       1 yes        
 8       3 aaa       2 yes        
 9       3 bbb       3 yes        
10       4 ccc       1 no         
11       4 aaa       2 no         
12       4 aaa       3 no         
13       4 aaa       4 no         
14       4 aaa       5 no
```

Giving me a wrong result, since `user_id` == 2 has not changed, since it has always had the flag `bbb`.

My desired output should look like:

```
# A tibble: 14 x 4
   user_id flag  order has_changed
     <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>      
 1       1 aaa       1 yes        
 2       1 aaa       2 yes        
 3       1 aaa       3 yes        
 4       1 bbb       4 yes        
 5       2 bbb       1 no         
 6       2 bbb       2 no         
 7       3 aaa       1 yes        
 8       3 aaa       2 yes        
 9       3 bbb       3 yes        
10       4 ccc       1 no         
11       4 aaa       2 no         
12       4 aaa       3 no         
13       4 aaa       4 no         
14       4 aaa       5 no
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, you want to identify `user_id` such that for `order == 1`, you have `flag != bbb`, and also that at some subsequent `order != 1`, `flag == bbb`.

If we spell out this logic, we write

```
library(tidyverse)

test_df %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  mutate(first_bbb = any(flag != 'bbb' & order == 1),
         subsequent_not_bbb = any(flag == 'bbb' & order != 1),
         has_changed = if_else(first_bbb & subsequent_not_bbb, 'yes', 'no'))
```

which produces

```
# A tibble: 14 x 6
# Groups:   user_id [4]
   user_id flag  order first_bbb subsequent_not_bbb has_changed
     <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <lgl>     <lgl>              <chr>      
 1       1 aaa       1 TRUE      TRUE               yes        
 2       1 aaa       2 TRUE      TRUE               yes        
 3       1 aaa       3 TRUE      TRUE               yes        
 4       1 bbb       4 TRUE      TRUE               yes        
 5       2 bbb       1 FALSE     TRUE               no         
 6       2 bbb       2 FALSE     TRUE               no         
 7       3 aaa       1 TRUE      TRUE               yes        
 8       3 aaa       2 TRUE      TRUE               yes        
 9       3 bbb       3 TRUE      TRUE               yes        
10       4 ccc       1 TRUE      FALSE              no         
11       4 aaa       2 TRUE      FALSE              no         
12       4 aaa       3 TRUE      FALSE              no         
13       4 aaa       4 TRUE      FALSE              no         
14       4 aaa       5 TRUE      FALSE              no
```

The `has_changed` column conforms to your desired output. You may of course pipe into `select(user_id, flag, order, has_changed)` to completely reproduce your desired output. Alternatively, here's a slightly more succinct (if perhaps less readable) version:

```
library(tidyverse)

test_df %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  mutate(has_changed = if_else(any(flag != 'bbb' & order == 1) & any(flag == 'bbb' & order != 1), 'yes', 'no'))
```

which gives

```
# A tibble: 14 x 4
# Groups:   user_id [4]
   user_id flag  order has_changed
     <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>      
 1       1 aaa       1 yes        
 2       1 aaa       2 yes        
 3       1 aaa       3 yes        
 4       1 bbb       4 yes        
 5       2 bbb       1 no         
 6       2 bbb       2 no         
 7       3 aaa       1 yes        
 8       3 aaa       2 yes        
 9       3 bbb       3 yes        
10       4 ccc       1 no         
11       4 aaa       2 no         
12       4 aaa       3 no         
13       4 aaa       4 no         
14       4 aaa       5 no
```

as desired.

Answer (score 0):

For a `user_id` if there is `any` value that has `flag` value as `'bbb'` and previous value which is not `'bbb'` then return `'yes'` for the group or else return `'no'`.

```
library(dplyr)

test_df %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  mutate(has_changed = if(any(flag == 'bbb' & 
                         lag(flag) != 'bbb', na.rm = TRUE)) 'yes' else 'no') %>%
  ungroup

#  user_id flag  order has_changed
#     <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <chr>      
# 1       1 aaa       1 yes        
# 2       1 aaa       2 yes        
# 3       1 aaa       3 yes        
# 4       1 bbb       4 yes        
# 5       2 bbb       1 no         
# 6       2 bbb       2 no         
# 7       3 aaa       1 yes        
# 8       3 aaa       2 yes        
# 9       3 bbb       3 yes        
#10       4 ccc       1 no         
#11       4 aaa       2 no         
#12       4 aaa       3 no         
#13       4 aaa       4 no         
#14       4 aaa       5 no
```